# XCode 7: view controller is not using entire screen on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller, screen-size

I am testing an IOS app that we developed for the iPhone 4 (ie a smaller screen size) and now when testing it on iPhone5 the view controllers do not expand to use the bigger iPhone 5 screen.

The view controllers remain the same size (fitted for the iPhone 4) and therefore leave a black strip above and below all view controllers in the app.

I've tried changing the size of the view controllers in story board by changing the "Simulated Size" parameter from Fixed to Freeform and setting the width and height to 320x568 for iPhone 5.  This changes the view controllers in storyboard just fine making them look taller but when I run in the simulator or on an iPhone5 the view controllers do not change size to use the expanded space on the iPhone5.

Any ideas anyone?  (thanks in advance)

Comment: also, I originally developed the app using XCode 5 and now am using XCode 7 so wonder if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: Do you use "autolayout"? or

Comment: I think you forget to setup Auto Layout & constraints.

Comment: Yes, my storyboard use autolayout; or at least the check box is check for autolayout

Comment: Have you included an iPhone 5 sized launch image or adopted a launch image storyboard?  If not then your app will run in iPhone 4 mode

Comment: hmm. the launch image idea didnt work either.  I think it has something to do with the fact that my app was developed with an older version of XCode.  thank you all for the quick responses

Comment: Paulw11, you are so right !!!! this worked.  Thank you :)